# Asynchronous Javascript Queues

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, queue

From what I know, the javascript event loop consists of the call stack (current tasks), the Web API (setTimeout and event listeners), and the task queue (tasks waiting for call stack to clear). However, where do asynchronous tasks go if they don’t wait for the call stack to clear? Do they have their own event loop? How do they differ from multiple threads or web workers?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the answer is that asynchronous tasks do wait for the call stack to clear before they run. Do you have reason to believe they don't?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by asynchronous tasks?

Comment: @RockySims By asynchronous tasks, I mean asynchronous functions like fetch().